# URL generated by generateEmailVerificationLink()

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to configure the `generateEmailVerificationLink()` to generate different URLs for different environments?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links

It looks like the only way is to configure it in the Firebase Console by following the steps below.
Authentication > Templates > customize action URL
This only allows me to set one URL per Firebase project.
However, when run from localhost, I want the link to be generated with the localhost domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set that URL based on any environment. You can however set the redirect URL to `localhost` in [`actionCodeSettings`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.actioncodesettings.md#actioncodesettings_interface) so you are redirected back to your local site after the link is used.